# Nuxt3 Apollo Only Allows One Auth Header When Making Queries / Mutations

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, nuxt.js, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to create a headless woocommerce application with [Nuxt3](https://nuxt.com/), [wpgraphql](https://www.wpgraphql.com/) and [Nuxt Apollo](https://apollo.nuxtjs.org/). So far I have been able to create a cart session and everything works well.

However, I am now trying to implement a way to have a user login with their site credentials and have their cart auto-populate.

I am able to get the guest cart session to work **or** the login but not both because they require two seperate headers that doesn't seem to work with Nuxt Apollo because it forces you to use one 'auth header' ([see here](https://apollo.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/configuration))

The cart session is using a woocommerce-session header, while the cart relies on a JWT authorization header (I am implementing it with this wp plugin, [JWT wpgraphql](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-jwt-authentication).

The 'woocommerce-session' header will work upon page load and the for the login I am using a mutation that passing back a JWT and this [onLogin Nuxt Apollo](https://apollo.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/auth-helpers#onlogin) function.

I am sure I am doing something wrong because it seems crazy to me that you can't have more than one header being passed with an apollo client within this library.

Here is what my apollo plugin looks like:

apollo.js (Nuxt3 Plugin)

```
import {
    createHttpLink,
  ApolloLink,
  from,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloClient
} from '@apollo/client/core';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { provideApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const wooJWT = useCookie('woo-jwt');
  const wooSession = useCookie('woo-session', {
    maxAge: 86_400,
    sameSite: 'lax'
  });

  const config = useRuntimeConfig();

  // wordpress backend graphql link
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: config.public.graphqlURL
  });

  // authentication headers
  const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    console.log('wooSession.value', wooSession.value);
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: wooJWT.value ? `Bearer ${wooJWT.value}` : '',
        'woocommerce-session': wooSession.value
          ? `Session ${wooSession.value}`
          : ``
      }
    };
  });

  const afterware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) =>
    forward(operation).map((response) => {
      /**
       * Check for session header and update session in local storage accordingly.
       */
      const context = operation.getContext();
      const {
        response: { headers }
      } = context;
      const session = headers.get('woocommerce-session');
      console.log('woo sesh: ', session);

      if (process.client && session) {
        if (session !== wooSession.value) {
          wooSession.value = session;
        }
      }

      return response;
    })
  );

  // Cache implementation
  const cache = new InMemoryCache();

  // Create the apollo client
  const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: from([authLink, afterware, httpLink]),
    cache
  });

  provideApolloClient(apolloClient);

  /** 1. the 'apollo:auth' hook must be commented out for the JWT code to work **/

  // retrieve and reset the given token 
  nuxtApp.hook('apollo:auth', ({ client, token }) => {
    token.value = wooSession.value;
  });
});
```

nuxt.config.ts

!! This is where the Auth option gets set

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...

  apollo: {
    /** 2. THIS ALLOWS THE 'woocommerce-session' HEADER TO BE PASSED AND UPDATED CORRECTLY. 
        THE JWT CODE BELOW WILL NOT WORK IF THIS IS LEFT UNCOMMENTED **/
    authType: 'Session',
    authHeader: 'woocommerce-session',
    tokenStorage: 'cookie',
    tokenName: 'woocommerce-session',
    /**  END  **/

    clients: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: process.env.PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_URL,
        httpLinkOptions: {
          credentials: 'include'
        }

        /** 3. UNCOMMENTING THIS WILL ALLOW JWT AUTH **/

        **// authType: 'Bearer',
        // authHeader: 'Authorization',
        // tokenStorage: 'cookie'**
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer despite there being no documentation on this.

I had to completely remove the `apollo:auth` hook and replaced it with `nuxtApp._apolloClients.default = apolloClient` at the end of the apollo.js plugin mentioned above to override the default apollo client with my own apollo client instance.